# LibCurl- How to update a specific header information which is aleady set?

Tags: c++, libcurl

I need to modify a specific information like authorization token in the header request. Is there any way to update only that specific header, keeping the rest? Currently I am doing something like below. But not sure if there is any other way to do it?

```
        struct curl_slist* headers = NULL;

        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:");

        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: ABCDC0F725997BEF3C6B90B0E39D9C314DCB58553FA47CD3598BBB8910A8CE6E");

        headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Host: localhost");

        curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);


        //Updating the header like this
        auto *test = headers;

        while (test != NULL)
        {
            if (strstr(test->data, "Authorization:"))
            {
                strcpy_s(test->data, strlen("Authorization: A5484526D0F7A671ABCD0C091755532A63475719E460ED6A807C4AAD70BCEDA0") + 1, "Authorization: A5484526D0F7A671CE400C091755532A63475719E460ED6A807C4AAD70BCEDA0");
                break;
            }
            test = test->next;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you can't do it like you implemented it. The allocated size of `test->data` is unknown. Your code will work only if the header length is fixed.

The libcurl code may be change, so `free(test->data); test->data = strdup(newdata)` is not a good idea.

I would do like bellow.

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

#if LIBCURL_VERSION_MAJOR != 7 || LIBCURL_VERSION_MINOR != 79 || LIBCURL_VERSION_PATCH != 1
# error "libcurl version is is changed. Be sure Curl_slist_duplicate is not changed in lib/slist.h"
#endif

struct curl_slist *Curl_slist_duplicate(struct curl_slist *inlist);

struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
struct curl_slist* commonheaders = nullptr;
commonheaders = curl_slist_append(commonheaders, "Accept:");
commonheaders = curl_slist_append(commonheaders, "Host: localhost");

// Update the headers.
curl_slist_free_all(headers);
headers = Curl_slist_duplicate(commonheaders);
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: ABCDC0F725997BEF3C6B90B0E39D9C314DCB58553FA47CD3598BBB8910A8CE6E");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Or

```
#include <curl/curl.h>

struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
struct curl_slist* headers = nullptr;
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Accept:");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Host: localhost");
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: ABCDC0F725997BEF3C6B90B0E39D9C314DCB58553FA47CD3598BBB8910A8CE6E");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);

// Remove the last header.
curl_slist* h = headers;
for (curl_slist* next = h->next; next->next; h = next->next, next = h->next) {}
curl_slist_free_all(h->next);
h->next = nullptr;
// Append new header.
headers = curl_slist_append(headers, "Authorization: ABCDC0F725997BEF3C6B90B0E39D9C314DCB58553FA47CD3598BBB8910A8CE6E");

curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, headers);
```

Comment: `Curl_slist_duplicate` is not exposed, i need to add the code manually

Comment: @samnaction Yes, it is not exposed. That is why the declaration is in the line 7 of the first snippet.

Comment: Curl_slist_duplicate is not a function libcurl provides in its API and thus you need to write your own if you need one.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is dangerous for these two reasons:

1. `test->data` might not be long enough to hold the data copying and you'll end up writing data somewhere you shouldn't.
2. `test->data` might be longer that the data you are copying, thus the header will have unwanted data at the end.

Based in curl's [source code](https://github.com/curl/curl/blob/master/lib/slist.c), it looks like breaking the abstraction will work ok so we can use your approach of setting `test->data` but with the following modification:

```
static const char *newheaderdata = "Authorization: A5484526D0F7A671CE400C091755532A63475719E460ED6A807C4AAD70BCEDA0";
while (test != NULL)
{
    if (strstr(test->data, "Authorization:"))
    {
        free(test->data);
        test->data = strdup(newheaderdata) 
        break;
    }
    test = test->next;
}
```